# How to use 2 jQuery checkboxradio groups at 1 div separately?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

please advise, how can I use 2 groups of checkboxradio separately? 
I want one of  "lang" and one of "currency" be active same time!

```
        <div class="radiobuttons">

            <div class="lang">    
                <label for="radio-en">EN</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-en">
                <label for="radio-fr">FR</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-fr">
                <label for="radio-gm">GM</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-gm">
            </div>

            <div class="currency">
                <label for="radio-dollars">$</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-dollars">
                <label for="radio-euro">€</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-euro">
                <label for="radio-funt">£</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-funt">
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
 $( "#radio-en, #radio-fr, #radio-gm, #radio-dollars, #radio-euro, #radio-funt").checkboxradio({
  icon: false
   });
   $( "#lang, #currency").controlgroup();

});

Comment: Use the radiobuttons name property to group them by, thats what it is there for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

> You can have as many radio groups on a page as you like, as long as each has its own unique name.

Use it like this:

```
  <div class="radiobuttons">

        <div class="lang">    
            <label for="radio-en">EN</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-lang" id="radio-en">
            <label for="radio-fr">FR</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-lang" id="radio-fr">
            <label for="radio-gm">GM</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-lang" id="radio-gm">
        </div>

        <div class="currency">
            <label for="radio-dollars">$</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-currency" id="radio-dollars">
            <label for="radio-euro">€</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-currency" id="radio-euro">
            <label for="radio-funt">£</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-currency" id="radio-funt">
        </div>

    </div>
```

Notice different `names` different groups